# How to set a default year while opening the date picker in android (But while scrolling the year it needs to show other years till current year)

Tags: java, android, datepicker

How to set a default year while opening the date picker in android.

I need to show the deafult date pickers year as back to 10 years. But while scrolling it needs to show the years upto the current date.

My code is like this

datePicker.setMaxDate(DateUtils.addYears(c.getTime(), 0).getTime());

Answer (score 0):

I assume that c is Date object which represent the current time?

Have you tried datePicker.updateDate(c.getYear() + 1900 - 10, c.getMonth(), c.getDate()) method?

This should setup the correct date.
c.getYear() returns the current year starting from 1900, but the date picker require normal year (starting from 0), so we add 1900. We need the date back to 10 years, so we substract 10.

Comment: I already have updateDate method like updating the year, month and date. datePicker.updateDate(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));